# Is it recommended to have a initial-scale < 1?

Tags: html, css, screen, viewport

So, I built my site in desktop form before doing mobile form. I saw that changing the initial-scale less than 1, for my case 0.6 (60%) works great! Is there any known side affects for people if I use this low scale? It seems fine with chrome inspect with different screens, and I just wanted to make sure this is good incase I post this to the internet.

60%:
[60% (0.6) initial-scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSvzn.png)

100%:
[100% (1.0) initial-scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xSYh.png)

I tried many scales, 60% worked best coming from desktop form. I'm currently concerned if using a lower than default initial-scale is good for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally not recommended to use an initial-scale value of less than 1. This is because doing so can cause the content of your website to appear smaller than intended on mobile devices, making it difficult for users to read and interact with your site. It's generally better to use a scale of 1 or higher and responsive design techniques to ensure your site looks good on mobile devices. This will help ensure that your site is accessible and easy to use for all users, regardless of their device.